# Read a PDF document in Blazor WebAssembly with iText7

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I am having a bit of a struggle reading a PDF using iText7 in Blazor WebAssembly.

The InputFile component creates a IBrowserFile:

```
<div>
    <InputFile OnChange="@OnFileSelection"></InputFile>
    <div class="row">
        <textarea>@outputText</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can then read the file with Stream - and iText7 will supposedly read that - but it won't give a page count or anything else that I have tried.  It also doesn't seem to pass over the reader, and doesn't even seem to get to the pageCount.

```
    int pageCount = 0;
    IBrowserFile pdfFile = e.File;
    Stream stream = pdfFile.OpenReadStream();
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(stream));
    pageCount = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
    stream.Close();
    outputText = $"{pageCount}";
    StateHasChanged();
```

I have also tried reading the Stream into a MemoryStream first, same outcome.  I have followed the information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly

Same outcome.

Is there a way to handle the PDF file in such a way as the functionality of iText7 remains intact, so you can get page counts, extracted text etc?

The file I am testing on is below the 500kb limit, it is 66kb.  I don't need to display the PDF - I just need to know what the contents of it are ideally on a page by page basis, but for now, simply being able to read a page or get a page count would be a big step forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your developer console, you'll find that it's emitting the error:

> Synchronous reads are not supported.

You'll notice you aren't using `await` anywhere, and, unfortunately, neither is iText7.  Blazor strongly enforces use of asynchronous semantics and if it's violated, you'll see an error like this.

Fortunately, you can still make this work. You said:

> I have also tried reading the Stream into a MemoryStream first, same outcome.

You should show what you tried, but my hunch is it looked something like this:

```
var copy = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(copy);
copy.Position = 0;
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(copy));
```

This will lead to the exact same error on the line `.CopyTo`.  And for the same reasons.  If you instead make the copy process properly use async semantics, it will work:

```
var copy = new MemoryStream();
await stream.CopyToAsync(copy);
copy.Position = 0;
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(copy));
```

Notice `await stream.CopyToAsync(copy);`.  You'll need to make your surrounding method `async` in order for the `await` to work, but the return type ought to be a `Task` already.  (And if it isn't, you can make it so)

Using this, I was able to see the page count display in your text area.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is in a task and I had used Async methods previously, so many iterations I wasn't sure which ones to post.  It appears to me that the part that was missing was this: "copy.Position = 0" - I have not seen that anywhere before in all of my reading.  This now works, so appreciate your help.